# Core Data Lock because of merge?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

I have a refresh process that runs in the background (just using performInBackground is all) and part of that has db updates so I have a separate MOC for the background thread. I then use the didSave notification to merge in the changes to the main MOC. While the app is refreshing in background, the user can click around the UI.

Mostly works, but i'm seeing some locks every now and then. When I look at the method called before the lock, its something that accesses the main MOC. Nothing in my refresh process accesses this, everything accesses a background MOC. BUT, I was thinking that the changes i make to the background MOC do get merged using the didSave notification. If I try to query one MOC while its doing mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, would that be the issue? What's the best way around this? I thought I had solved my db issues with a separate MOC for my background thread, but the merge is gonna be an issue right?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Each thread using its own MOC; and main UI thread getting notifications when background thread updates the data. There is nothing in what you describe that can result in a lock. The locks you experience are most likely a result of long running code executing in the main thread, blocking the UI, while you think this processing is being done in a background thread.

Comment: thanks so much! so the merge isnt the issue? i was worried accessing a moc thats merging would be an issue, but it can handle that? i dont need a third MOC (one main, one background, one for background to merge into) or anything like that? can you expand on possible cause of the lock? i don't think ive run into this before with my code, only now after rearchitecting for the background stuff. for example, ill initiate and then not do anything else with the UI, i just let it go. But im still seeing [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock], [_PFLock lock], pthread_mutex_lock, _psynch_mutexwait

Comment: No need for a 3rd MOC for what you describe. I have experienced locks when code runs in the main thread but I did not intend for it to; for example if you do any data processing on callbacks and notifications that execute on the main thread. My main moc is allocated as follows: newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType], my background one just: newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init].

Comment: thanks so much for response, good to know i dont need a third. so how does it work if in my main thread im accessing the main MOC? i can access it and it knows how to give me data even while it might be merging? do i need to call the merge on the main thread? my main MOC i do with alloc init as well, but no concurrency type. is that as easy to use as just using that during init?

Comment: sorry for late reply; see http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/ as one example. If you search for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and Marcus Zara you will find a lot of great articles and explanations of how to do this. You are on the right track; keep it simple and follow the recommendations from the references I provided.

Comment: thanks so much! i feel like im close! ill take a look at the links you mentioned.